# Decrease by -1 with Join (PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, join

another MySQL question here. I am trying to decrease the product_qty by -1 based on product ID's which are stored in another table. In tbl_basket I have a column called product_id which contains a product ID which is also located in column product_id which is located in tbl_products. I want to decrease the product_qty by -1 based on the product id's in tbl_basket, where the User is the same as the session. So far I have:

```
$purchase = mysql_query("
UPDATE tbl_products a SET a.product_quantity = a.product_quantity -1
WHERE a.product_id IN (SELECT product_id
  from tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'");
```

This is not working for me. It does not decrease the product_qty. Any ideas what it could be? Thank you.

It was an issue with the parethesis as mentioned by Patrick Q.

The working query is:

```
$purchase = "UPDATE tbl_products a SET a.product_quantity = a.product_quantity -1 WHERE a.product_id IN (SELECT product_id from tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "')";
$debug = mysql_query($purchase) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$purchase);
```

Comment: what is not working? Are you getting errors? Is the query reporting any updated rows? Please be more descriptive and debug a little.

Comment: The query fails and does not update anything.

Comment: Fails with what error message? You need to debug your problem!

Comment: what is the data type of `product_quantity`? When you execute this query, does it return data? `SELECT product_id
  from tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'"`

Comment: Sorry. the error is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 UPDATE tbl_products a SET a.product_quantity = a.product_quantity -1 WHERE a.product_id IN (SELECT product_id from tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = 'user@user.com' in

Comment: You should definitely be getting an error.  Your parenthesis are closed in the wrong spot. You need to close it before your final double-quote, in addition to after (to close the inner select, and then the function).

Comment: Yes thank you. It was an issue with my parenthesis.

Comment: Voted to close for typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis for your subquery.

```
$purchase = mysql_query("
UPDATE tbl_products a SET a.product_quantity = a.product_quantity -1
WHERE a.product_id IN (SELECT product_id
  from tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "');");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parenthesis of the subquery:

```
$purchase = mysql_query("
UPDATE tbl_products a SET a.product_quantity = a.product_quantity -1
WHERE a.product_id IN (SELECT product_id
  from tbl_basket WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "')");
```